# How to send Custom proto in Details of grpc's status error object

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I'm trying to send a custom Proto in Error Response of my grpc calls. As per [this](https://jbrandhorst.com/post/grpc-errors/), it should be possible.

Here is the code.

```
    st := status.Newf(codes.NotFound, "user %s doesn't exist", req.Name)
    desc := "The username Doesn't exist, please give a valid username"

    customProtoError := &data.Error{
        Message:         "Check username",
        Code:            1404,
        Type:            "Service",
        DetailedMessage: desc,
    }

    st, err := st.WithDetails(customProtoError)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Unexpected error attaching metadata: %v", err))
    }
```

I've both grpc & http Handlers for these GRPC APIs.
The Marshaler used in HTTP server is `github.com/gogo/gateway`

```
mux := runtime.NewServeMux(
    runtime.WithMarshalerOption(JSONContentType, &gateway.JSONPb{}))
```

The configuration for [HTTP](https://github.com/bandikishores/TestGo/blob/master/pkg/protocol/rest-server.go) and [GRPC](https://github.com/bandikishores/TestGo/blob/master/pkg/protocol/grpc-server.go) server is available here.
When I try to access the API using HTTP calls, here is what I get in response.

**HTTP Error:**

```
{
    "error": "user kishore1 doesn't exist",
    "code": 5,
    "message": "user kishore1 doesn't exist",
    "details": [
        {
            "type_url": "type.googleapis.com/data.Error",
            "value": "Cg5DaGVjayB1c2VybmFtZRD8ChoHU2t5ZmxvdyI4VGhlIHVzZXJuYW1lIERvZXNuJ3QgZXhpc3QsIHBsZWFzZSBnaXZlIGEgdmFsaWQgdXNlcm5hbWU="
        }
    ]
}
```

The `type_url` is coming with google, as its hardcoded in the [golang proto code](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/blob/master/ptypes/any.go#L55). But [this says](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Any) `Any` in JSON will be deserialized to embedded messages.

**Grpc Client Code:**

```
resp, err := client.GetUser(ctx, req)
        if err != nil {
        st := status.Convert(err)
        for _, detail := range st.Details() {
            switch t := detail.(type) {
            case *pb.Error:
                fmt.Println("Oops! Your request was rejected by the server.")
                ...
            default:
                fmt.Println("Error Received - ", detail, reflect.TypeOf(detail))
            }
        }
```

**Grpc Error:**

```
Error Received - proto: not found *errors.prefixError
```

Any idea what could be causing this mess? HTTP doesn't deserialize as an embedded message and GRPC gives `proto.NotFound`

Could this be due to gogo proto being the gateway? I even tried the same with googleapis proto `errdetails.BadRequest` but still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending about a day, I just figured out the issue was due to incompatible versions.
So here is what worked for me, when using gogo proto.

For the GRPC errors, I had to upgrade my grpc-gateway version and use `gogo/status` instead of `grpc/status`

```
github.com/gogo/status v1.1.0
github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway v1.14.5
```

For HTTP errors, I had to downgrade my `golang/protobuf`

```
github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.2
```

Comment: I also stumbled upon this, however I am not using gogo proto, but [`grpc-gateway`](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway), after spending much time on the customization, I found out as long as I have imported the generated custom error from the proto anywhere in my code, the gateway is able to deserialize the details correctly